# UDP Sending and Receiving

Tags: java, android, udp

I've looking into multiple ways to do this and nothing has helped/worked new to Java UDP packets.

My code for Android is started via a service and it runs on a new thread.

Code for waiting:

```
        try {
            int port = 58452;

            // Create a socket to listen on the port.
            DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

            // Create a buffer to read datagrams into. If a
            // packet is larger than this buffer, the
            // excess will simply be discarded!
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            // Now loop forever, waiting to receive packets and printing them.
            while (true) {
                // Wait to receive a datagram
                dsocket.receive(packet);

                // Convert the contents to a string, and display them
                String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
                System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "
                        + msg);

                // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
                packet.setLength(buffer.length);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

Code for sending:

```
 try {
      String host = "MY PHONES IP";
      int port = 58452; //Random Port

      byte[] message = "LAWL,LAWL,LAWL".getBytes();

      // Get the internet address of the specified host
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

      // Initialize a datagram packet with data and address
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length,
          address, port);

      // Create a datagram socket, send the packet through it, close it.
      DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
      dsocket.send(packet);
      dsocket.close();
      System.out.println("Sent");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
```

It sends fine but won't receive on Android. Please help!

Also my Logcat output: http://pastebin.com/Rfw5mSKV

Thanks
-Fusion

Comment: Have you tried to receive on the same machine? Are sure it is the correct ip and your router does not filter the port? On first glance the code seems ok ...

Comment: Yea I have tried like 10 or so ports. I will try on same machine!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/

I used that to and it works! Thanks to /u/TarkLark or Reddit!

Comment: dead link; best to put answer in your answer and have the link only for additional info/context/recognition